# How to show line chart and bar chart in the same Steema.TeeChart in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, teechart

I'm trying to show line chart and bar chart in the Steema.TeeChart its working for me.
Now I try to show both (line chart and bar chart) in same TeeChart is it possible to show in the same chart. when I try with this i get only line chart.

```
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line rline = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line ();
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line rCrtdayline = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line ();

Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar Currentbar = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar (rainfallChart.Chart);
Currentbar.Marks.Visible = false;

rainfallChart.Series.Add (rline);
rainfallChart.Series.Add (rCrtdayline); 
rainfallChart.Series.Add (Currentbar);
```

This is code I'm using, can any one help for this...

Comment: The code you posted looks correct... Just note in no one of the series seems to have any data. Make sure all them have data.

Comment: Hi @Yeray I add data in my code but not shown in the post. If I hide line chart, bar chart working otherwise always line chart only in visible

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot reproduce the problem using the following code, could you please check if it's working fine for you? 
I've just added a FillSampleValues lines of code and changed the chart object by the one used into the TeeChartBuilder demo included with the installer.

```
                    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line rline = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line ();
                Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line rCrtdayline = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line ();

                Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar Currentbar = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar (_controller.chart.Chart);
                Currentbar.Marks.Visible = false;

                _controller.chart.Series.Add (rline);
                _controller.chart.Series.Add (rCrtdayline); 
                _controller.chart.Series.Add (Currentbar);
                rline.FillSampleValues ();
                rCrtdayline.FillSampleValues ();
                Currentbar.FillSampleValues ();
```

If you still having problems, please post the complete code here so we can test and try to reproduce it.

Regards!
Pep